# How to select elements between ranges given by indices in a 2D array? Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Lets say I have an array

```
arr = np.random.randint(1000, size=(100,30))
```

And I have beginging and ending indices like

```
first= np.random.randint(5, size=(100,))
second = first + 20
```

How can I select the data from 2D array between ranges given by 1D array?

Currently I have a for loop to do the task

```
m =[]
for i,j in enumerate(arr):
    m.append(j[first[i]:second[i]])

np.array(m).shape

(100, 20)
```

How can I do the same in numpy or vectorize this solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and some `masking` -

```
def extract_rows(arr, first, second, fillval=0): 
    # Define the extent of output array
    L = (second.clip(max=arr.shape[1]-1) - first).max()

    # Get the ranged indices to cover the extent of cols for all rows
    idx = first[:,None] + range(L)

    # Now, the inices that are bounded by the limit of second values are to be
    # set as fillval. Similarly, the indices that go beoyn the extent of column
    # length of the input array are invalid as well. So, get the combined mask.
    invalid_mask = (idx >= arr.shape[1]) | ((second - first)[:,None] <= range(L))

    # Set invalid places in idx as zeros or just any value, but make sure those
    # are indexable into input array
    idx[invalid_mask] = 0

    # Finally index into input array with those and set the invalid ones in it
    # with fillval.
    return np.where(invalid_mask, fillval, arr[np.arange(len(idx))[:,None], idx])
```

Sample run -

1] Input array :

```
In [639]: arr
Out[639]: 
array([[87, 83, 36, 30, 58, 35, 85, 87],
       [17, 58, 51, 39, 56, 27, 97, 26],
       [33, 45,  1, 90, 87, 49, 30, 37],
       [92, 29, 17,  9, 81, 35, 47, 33],
       [61, 87, 22, 44, 97, 43, 96, 66],
       [47, 67, 28, 74, 50, 93, 22, 19],
       [77, 82, 35, 51, 25, 29, 25, 29],
       [95, 24, 70, 70, 34, 35, 50, 53],
       [53, 64, 84, 46, 21, 89, 44, 52],
       [92, 78, 21, 53, 53, 39,  7, 59]])
```

2] Input start, stop indices per row :

```
In [640]: np.c_[first, second]
Out[640]: 
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 0,  6],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 3, 12],
       [ 2,  8],
       [ 2,  4],
       [ 4, 12],
       [ 0,  0],
       [ 2,  7],
       [ 4,  6]])
```

3] Output array :

```
In [652]: extract_rows(arr, first, second)
Out[652]: 
array([[87,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [17, 58, 51, 39, 56, 27],
       [ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 9, 81, 35, 47, 33,  0],
       [22, 44, 97, 43, 96, 66],
       [28, 74,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [25, 29, 25, 29,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [84, 46, 21, 89, 44,  0],
       [53, 39,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

Comment: Sir, how can I use `second` rather than range(20) because that was just to illustrate an example. I have an array of begining and ending ranges. I know the shape varies so I want to fill the inconsitant shapes with nan or 0 is that possible?

Comment: @Bharath Okay, that changes things. Just to confirm, the final output would be a 3D array, right?

Comment: No sir, maybe I messed Up I want 2D array each row with elements between the corressponding ranges. Sorry if the question was misleading

Comment: Sir I updated my code , I misunderstood indexing earlier, updated for loop is what I want to vectorize. Sorry for confusing you

Comment: @Bharath Updated solution.

Comment: Sir what's the difference between clip and ordinary subtration? I mean why change from subtraction of second to clip and then subtract?

Comment: @Bharath Clipping helps in limiting the range for the output array here. Subtraction is still there as was before. The only addition is the clipping to limit output no. of cols, which had redundant zero cols before.

Comment: Sir can you do me a favor? Can you add comments on what each line is doing there. I usually take your solution, plug and play, and it works fantastic. After a month or so I understand the solution properly. So to avoid that It would be really helpful if you tell me what each line is doing here.

Comment: @Bharath Updated.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir now it makes sense to me .